# Is there a way to check if it's DST (Daylight Saving Time) with UTC?

Tags: c#, utc, dst

Is there a way to check if it's DST (Daylight Saving Time) with UTC, **without using conversion**?

I don't want to use conversion because it's ambiguous on the 28 october at 2 am. This:

```
using System;

namespace Rextester
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void PrintSeasonKindTime(DateTime utcDate)
        {
            // Convert dt to Romance Standard Time
            TimeZoneInfo tzi = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("W. Europe Standard Time");
            DateTime localDate = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(utcDate, tzi);

            Console.WriteLine("Local date: " + localDate.ToString("yyyy.MM.d HH:mm:ss") +  (tzi.IsDaylightSavingTime(localDate) ? " is summer" : " is winter"));
        }

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DateTime currentUTCDateTime = new DateTime(2018,10,27,23,59,0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
            double nbMinutes = 1.0;

            PrintSeasonKindTime(currentUTCDateTime);
            PrintSeasonKindTime(currentUTCDateTime.AddMinutes(nbMinutes));
        }
    }
}
```

Will display this:

```
Local date: 2018.10.28 01:59:00 is summer
Local date: 2018.10.28 02:00:00 is winter
```

While I wish the following display:

```
Local date: 2018.10.28 01:59:00 is summer
Local date: 2018.10.28 02:00:00 is summer
```

Since the time change is at 2018.10.28 03:00:00 local time in the specified time zone not at 2 am (see here [enter link description here](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/switzerland)).

However, that behaviour is "ambiguously" correct since it's two times 2 am on 28th October; once at 00:00 UTC (2 am summer time) and once at 1 am (2 am winter time). Do you have any idea?

Comment: DST is specific to countries (i.e., location, not timezone). UTC is just universal time. UTC does not contain any country-specific information, obviously. (Also, since DST is a feature/decision of a country, converting UTC to some other timezone won't really help)

Comment: DST is ambiguous by nature. There is no way to make it not ambiguous.

Comment: @elgonzo: If different countries have different DST rules, they would observe different time zones. Also, "country" is the wrong unit of granularity anyway: some countries observe multiple time zones, some of which observe DST and some of which don't. The US is an example of that.

Comment: "I don't want to use conversion because it's ambiguous on the 28 october at 2 am." Not at 2am *UTC*. If you've started with UTC, there's no ambiguity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use [`TimeZoneInfo.IsDaylightSavingTime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.timezoneinfo.isdaylightsavingtime), passing in your UTC `DateTime` value. That will *effectively* convert that UTC value into the given time zone and check whether the result is in daylight saving time, although whether it actually performs that conversion or just checks whether it *would* be in DST is a different matter.

Note that this is never ambiguous, as a UTC value is never ambiguous.

`TimeZoneInfo.IsDaylightSavingTime` returns `true` when passed 2018-10-28T00:00:00Z in the time zone you're interested in.

Comment: yes, because it's not the correct date. The correct datetime is 2018-10-**2**8T00:00:00Z

Comment: @AymenTurki: Sorry, fixed that part - but it still returns `true` :) (Basically I added `Console.WriteLine(tzi.IsDaylightSavingTime(utcDate));` into your sample code.)

Comment: Nice, thank you, I didn't try this I thought I had to pass a datetime corresponding to this timezone.

Answer (score 2):

It is impossible to get Daylight saving time from UTC, because it is UTC - check UTC description [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time#Daylight_saving_time)

You need the current timezone. With this information you can use [TimeZoneInfo.IsDaylightSavingTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460642(v=vs.110).aspx) to determine if the current TimeZone is currently in DST.

If you are storing data serverside (eg. web) you should always try to get the users timezone and convert to UTC.

Comment: DST is not a feature of a time zone! It is specific to individual countries!

Comment: Sure it is specific - what inside my post made you think this?

Comment: @dsdel maybe `TimeZoneInfo.IsDaylightSavingTime`?

Comment: @elgonzo: It really *is* a feature of a time zone. I think you may have misunderstood the meaning of "time zone".

Comment: Updated my post - hope I could better explain myself now. Thank you! : )

Comment: @JonSkeet *mis*understood?

Comment: Oh God I helped Jon Skeet fixing his comment O.O do I get a special badge for that? ^^

Comment: @JonSkeet, perhaps i do. I am under the impression that a time zone is a geographic region. But you seem to imply this is not exactly so. I guess i need to check my assumption...

Comment: @elgonzo: One way of thinking of a time zone is a geographic region (maybe larger than a country, maybe smaller) where the local time is always the same (and always *has* been the same). So given a location, you can get a time zone, and given a time zone, you can tell what the local time is for any instant in time. That's a bit of a simplification as there are places which have multiple local times at the same place depending on politics.

Comment: @JonSkeet, i get that. That was not the souce of my misunderstanding. I equaled timezone with time, which is incorrect. While a timezone has an associated standard time (i guess), countries/states/regions can decide to choose a time varying from the standard time (like with DST).

Comment: "If you are storing data serverside (eg. web) you should always try to get the users timezone and convert to UTC." Not always. It's not as simple as that, particularly for future dates and times... because the time zone information may change between now and then. It's complex - far more than I could put in comments.

Comment: @elgonzo: The standard time within a time zone can change as well, although that's relatively rare.

Comment: @dsdel Yes, I know you cannot get the DST with UTC alone. I meant something like `isDST(utcTime, timeZoneInfo)`, so we get rid of the local time ambiguity at 2 am on the 28th October.

Comment: @Aymen I have edited my post and hope I understood you correctly